# Reading command line arguments from stdin

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, argv

So I want to allow myself to run ./program so that it allows input for piping a text file.

EX: ./program < sometext.txt

I know that I can't get the data using argv, but I've been trying to google how to get it from stdin, and I can't seem to find the right keywords to google to get some basic understanding of how to do this. I'm sure it's done using scanf, but I still have a hard time trying to understand it.

Any sort of insight would be helpful, I don't need the exact code, though if it's simple enough, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a more specific question?  What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: I'm trying to take a text file and just put everything from it into a char array using the redirection operator as shown in the example, sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example (with no error checking) that reads `stdin` into a dynamically allocated character array and then prints it back to `stdout`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int bufferSize = 100;
    char *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    int length = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (length == bufferSize)
        {
            bufferSize *= 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, bufferSize);
        }

        buffer[length++] = c;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        putchar(buffer[j]);
    }

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: Makes sense, one question, with "buffer[i++] = c;" will that skip the first index of the array entirely?

Comment: No, `i++` uses the post-increment operator, which means it returns the value of `i` before the increment operation takes place.

Comment: Oh yeah I completely forgot about the "post-increment" part of it, thanks for clarifying.